# Dart keyword 'await' not recognized in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Consider the following Dart source code (Flutter project):

```
void foo() {
  await bar();
}

Future<void> bar() async {
  print("test");
}
```

This is causing the following error on Android Studio:
`The built-in identifier 'await' can't be used as a type`.

If I change it to `(await bar());` then I get the error `Unexpected text 'await'`.

What am I missing here?

[image: The built-in identifier 'await' can't be used as a type]
[image: Unexpected text 'await']

Comment: It has to be used inside an async function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `foo()` method needs to be marked with `async`.

```
Future<void> foo() async {
  await bar();
}
```

Comment: This is correct, thank you. I was feeling pretty stupid after this, so I re-read [the docs](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async#await-expressions) and indeed this "detail" is not immediately clear. I've misinterpreted it to be a shorthand for `asyncMethod().then(...)`.